# Algorithm for finding subset out of list that fulfills constraint

Tags: python, algorithm, math, graph, tree

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm to perform the following task. An implementation in python would be optimal, but using another language or just pseudocode would be helpful as well.

**Given** is a rational number *x* and a list of about 600 rational numbers. 
Out of that list i want to find a subset of 10 numbers (no repetitions) that fulfills the constraint

*s* = the sum of x in addition to the sum of the numbers in the subset

so that the absolute difference between *s* and the nearest integer number is less than 10e-12.

I guess that this might be done with some kind of graph algorithm but i have no idea how to do it.

**Example:** This is a naive approach to illustrate what i am looking for. Obviously this approach will be to inefficient for the amount of possible combinations that result out of a list and subset as large as given in the description:

```
#!/bin/python3

import sys
from math import pow
from itertools import combinations

x = 0.5
list = [1.000123,2.192,3.2143124,1.00041,2.0043,3.5]
for c in combinations(list,3):
    s = x + sum(c)
    r = s%1    
    if r <= pow(10,-3) or r >= 1-pow(10,-3):
        print("Found combination: s=%s for %s"%(s,c))
        break
```

**Example output:**

> Found combination: s=6.000533 for (1.000123, 1.00041, 3.5)

Comment: Are they all positive? How large/small can they be? How large is *x* compared to the other numbers?

Comment: @Blender It's only the fractional parts of the numbers that matter.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: You're right, thanks.

Comment: Thinking aloud: you can eliminate `x` from the problem altogether by subtracting `x/10` from all the numbers. This way it's enough to know how to solve "find 10 numbers from the set such that their sum is almost integer".

Comment: There is a typo in your example, you likely want `if r <= epsilon or r >= 1-epsilon` with `epsilon = pow(10,-3)`

Comment: An optimal solution can be found by solving at most 10 instances of 10-SUM, since you can remap any number in this problem into the range [0, 1).

Comment: @Blender : What is 10-SUM? Can you provide a link? When I Google N-SUM, nothing relevant appears

Comment: @Fezvez: It's just generalized [3-SUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM).

Comment: I don't think that's the case. OP accepts "nearly integral" solutions whereas N-SUM is about being exactly 0

Comment: @Fezvez: It doesn't really make a difference, you can implement it recursively and just change the stopping condition on the base case from strict equality to approximate equality. The runtime is still *O(n^5)*, which is pretty poor.

Comment: Because the mixed integer program didn't run as well as I expected, I have a solution at 4.10^-10 with this list : `[0.6491106406735181, 0.8284271247461903, 0.8309518948453007, 0.038404810405298306, 0.08276253029821934, 0.08304597359457233, 0.16227766016837952, 0.36931687685298087, 0.45362404707370985, 0.48528137423856954, 0.4868329805051381]`. When you sum this and `x` you get `4.999999999543545`

Comment: And now `[0.06225774829854913, 0.21267040355189515, 0.21954445729288707, 0.21954445729288707, 0.24621125123532117, 0.24621125123532117, 0.36931687685298087, 0.4017542509913792, 0.41421356237309515, 0.41640786499873883, 0.6619037896906015]` gives you an error of `4.4*10^-11`. I suggest you run my code overnight to try to get `10^-12` (took me 20 minutes to get `10^-11`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a heuristic solution using only numpy.

UPDATE: Please forgive my bragging, but be sure not to miss the very end of this post where we solve for k = 80 terms out of N = 1200 numbers at 10^-12 accuracy. The solver finds more than 100 solutions in just above 4 seconds on modest hardware.

Algorithm (for the N = 600, k = 10, eps = 10^-12 case):

It takes advantage of there statistically being lots and lots of solutions, and samples only a manageable subspace.

Indeed, if samples are evenly distributed it suffices to randomly test 4x10^12 sums for a >99.9% chance of finding a solution. This can be brought to tractable levels by splitting into two sets of 2x10^6 halfsums because one can then avoid computing most of the pairwise sums using a trick which only involves sorting 4x10^6 numbers, which can easily be done on current hardware.

This is how it works.

It chooses 10 disjoint random subsamples of 30 (can go down to 20 and still be pretty sure to find solutions), splits them in two and computes all 30**5 sums for each half. Then one half is subtracted from minus the input x. Everything is then reduced modulo 1 and sorted.

Among the differences between consecutive elements are typically a good 2,000 below the tolerance of 10^-12, half of which are between sums from the different halfs. All these are solutions.

Most of the complexity of the code is owed to tracing back the indirect sort.

```
import numpy as np
import time

def binom(N, k):
    return np.prod(np.arange(N, N-k, -1).astype(object)) \
        // np.prod(np.arange(2, k+1).astype(object))

def master(nlist, input, k=10, HS=10**7, eps=12, ntrials=10):
    for j in range(ntrials):
        res = trial(nlist, input, k=k, HS=HS, eps=eps)
        if not res is None:
            return res
     print("No solution found in", ntrials, "trials.")

def trial(nlist, input, k=10, HS=10**7, eps=12):
    tol = 10**-eps
    srps = str(eps)
    t0 = time.time()
    N = len(nlist)
    if 2**(k//2) > HS or k > 64:
        kk = min(2 * int (np.log(HS) / np.log(2)), 64)
    else:
        kk = k        
    kA, kB = (kk+1)//2, kk//2
    CA = min(int(HS**(1/kA)), (N+kk-k) // (kA+kB))
    CB = min(int(HS**(1/kB)), (N+kk-k) // (kA+kB))
    inds = np.random.permutation(N)
    indsA = np.reshape(inds[:kA*CA], (kA, CA))
    indsB = np.reshape(inds[kA*CA:kA*CA+kB*CB], (kB, CB))
    extra = inds[N-k+kk:]
    A = sum(np.ix_(*tuple(nlist[indsA]))).ravel() % 1
    B = (-input - nlist[extra].sum()
         - sum(np.ix_(*tuple(nlist[indsB]))).ravel()) % 1
    AB = np.r_[A, B]
    ABi = np.argsort(AB)
    AB = np.where(np.diff(AB[ABi]) < tol)[0]
    nsol = len(AB)
    if nsol == 0:
        return None
     # translate back ...
    ABl = ABi[AB]
    ABh = ABi[AB+1]
    ABv = (ABl >= CA**kA) != (ABh >= CA**kA)
    nsol = np.count_nonzero(ABv)
    if nsol == 0:
        return None
    ABl, ABh = ABl[ABv], ABh[ABv]
    Ai = np.where(ABh >= CA**kA, ABl, ABh)
    Bi = np.where(ABh < CA**kA, ABl, ABh) - CA**kA
    Ai = np.unravel_index(Ai, kA * (CA,))
    Bi = np.unravel_index(Bi, kB * (CB,))
    solutions = [np.r_[indsA[np.arange(kA), Aii],
                       indsB[np.arange(kB), Bii], extra]
                 for Aii, Bii in zip(np.c_[Ai], np.c_[Bi])]
    total_time = time.time() - t0
    for sol in solutions:
        print(("{:."+srps+"f}  =  {:."+srps+"f}  " + "\n".join([
            j * (" + {:."+srps+"f}") for j
            in np.diff(np.r_[0, np.arange(4, k, 6), k])])).format(
                   nlist[sol].sum() + input, input, *nlist[sol]))
    print("\n{} solutions found in {:.3f} seconds, sampling {:.6g}% of"
          " available space.".format(nsol, total_time,
                                     100 * (CA**kA + CB**kB) / binom(N, k)))
    return solutions
```

Output:

```
a = np.random.random(600)
b = np.random.random()
s = trial(a, b)
...
<  --   snip   --  >
...
5.000000000000  =  0.103229509601  + 0.006642137376 + 0.312241735755 + 0.784266426461 + 0.902345822935 + 0.988978878589
 + 0.973861938944 + 0.191460799437 + 0.131957251738 + 0.010524218878 + 0.594491280285
5.999999999999  =  0.103229509601  + 0.750882954181 + 0.365709602773 + 0.421458098864 + 0.767072742224 + 0.689495123832
 + 0.654006237725 + 0.418856927051 + 0.892913889958 + 0.279342774349 + 0.657032139442
6.000000000000  =  0.103229509601  + 0.765785564962 + 0.440313432133 + 0.987713329856 + 0.785837107607 + 0.018125214584
 + 0.742834214592 + 0.820268051141 + 0.232822918386 + 0.446038517697 + 0.657032139442
5.000000000001  =  0.103229509601  + 0.748677981958 + 0.708845535002 + 0.330115345473 + 0.660387831821 + 0.549772082712
 + 0.215300958403 + 0.820268051141 + 0.258387204727 + 0.010524218878 + 0.594491280285
5.000000000001  =  0.103229509601  + 0.085365104308 + 0.465618675355 + 0.197311784789 + 0.656004057436 + 0.595032922699
 + 0.698000899403 + 0.546925212167 + 0.844915369567 + 0.333326991548 + 0.474269473129

1163 solutions found in 18.431 seconds, sampling 0.000038% of available space.
```

Since only simple operations are used we are essentially only limited by floating point accuracy. So let's ask for 10^-14:

```
...
<  --   snip   --  >
...
6.00000000000000  =  0.25035941161807  + 0.97389388071258 + 0.10625051346950 + 0.59833873712725 + 0.89897827417947
 + 0.78865856416474 + 0.35381392162358 + 0.87346871541364 + 0.53658653353249 + 0.21248261924724 + 0.40716882891145
5.00000000000000  =  0.25035941161807  + 0.24071288846314 + 0.48554094441439 + 0.50713200488770 + 0.38874292843933
 + 0.86313933327877 + 0.90048328572856 + 0.49027844783527 + 0.23879340585229 + 0.10277432242557 + 0.53204302705691
5.00000000000000  =  0.25035941161807  + 0.38097649901116 + 0.48554094441439 + 0.46441170824601 + 0.62826547862002
 + 0.86313933327877 + 0.33939826575779 + 0.73873418282621 + 0.04398883198337 + 0.62252491844691 + 0.18266042579730
3.00000000000000  =  0.25035941161807  + 0.06822167273996 + 0.23678340695986 + 0.46441170824601 + 0.08855356615846
 + 0.00679943782685 + 0.74823208211878 + 0.56709685813503 + 0.44549706663049 + 0.05232395855097 + 0.07172083101554
4.99999999999999  =  0.25035941161807  + 0.02276077008953 + 0.29734365315824 + 0.74952397467956 + 0.74651313615300
 + 0.06942795892486 + 0.33939826575779 + 0.28515053127059 + 0.75198496353405 + 0.95549430775741 + 0.53204302705691
6.00000000000000  =  0.25035941161807  + 0.87635507011986 + 0.24113470302798 + 0.37942029808604 + 0.08855356615846
 + 0.30383588785334 + 0.79224372764376 + 0.85138208150978 + 0.76217062127440 + 0.76040834996762 + 0.69413628274069
5.00000000000000  =  0.25035941161807  + 0.06822167273996 + 0.51540640390940 + 0.91798512102932 + 0.63568890016512
 + 0.75300966489960 + 0.30826232152132 + 0.54179156374890 + 0.30349257203507 + 0.63406153731771 + 0.07172083101554

11 solutions found in 18.397 seconds, sampling 0.000038% of available space.
```

Or we can reduce the number of samples for a faster execution time:

```
...
<  --   snip   -- >
...
4.999999999999  =  0.096738768432  + 0.311969906774 + 0.830155028676 + 0.164375548024 + 0.118447437942
 + 0.362452121111 + 0.676458354204 + 0.627931895727 + 0.568131437959 + 0.579341106837 + 0.663998394313
5.000000000000  =  0.096738768432  + 0.682823940439 + 0.768308425728 + 0.290242415733 + 0.303087635772
 + 0.776829608333 + 0.229947280121 + 0.189745700730 + 0.469824524584 + 0.795706660727 + 0.396745039400
6.000000000000  =  0.096738768432  + 0.682823940439 + 0.219502575013 + 0.164375548024 + 0.853518966685
 + 0.904544718964 + 0.272487275000 + 0.908201512199 + 0.570219149773 + 0.840338947058 + 0.487248598411
6.000000000001  =  0.096738768432  + 0.838905554517 + 0.837179741796 + 0.655925596548 + 0.121227619542
 + 0.393276631434 + 0.529706372738 + 0.627931895727 + 0.857852927706 + 0.827365021028 + 0.213889870533
5.000000000000  =  0.096738768432  + 0.037789824744 + 0.219502575013 + 0.578848374222 + 0.618570311975
 + 0.393356108716 + 0.999687645216 + 0.163539900985 + 0.734447052985 + 0.840338947058 + 0.317180490652
5.000000000001  =  0.096738768432  + 0.093352607179 + 0.600306836676 + 0.914256455483 + 0.618570311975
 + 0.759417445766 + 0.252660056506 + 0.422864494209 + 0.298221673761 + 0.456362751604 + 0.487248598411

25 solutions found in 1.606 seconds, sampling 0.000001% of available space.
```

Finally, it scales easily:

```
N = 1200; a = np.random.random(N)
b = np.random.random()
k = 80; s = nt6.trial(a, b, k)
```

Output:

```
...
<  --   snip   --  >
...
37.000000000000  =  0.189587827991   + 0.219870655535 + 0.422462560363 + 0.446529942912 + 0.340513300967
 + 0.272272603670 + 0.701821613150 + 0.016414376458 + 0.228845802410 + 0.071882553217 + 0.966675626054
 + 0.947578041095 + 0.016404068780 + 0.010927217220 + 0.160372498474 + 0.498852167218 + 0.018622555121
 + 0.199963779290 + 0.977205343235 + 0.272323870374 + 0.468492667326 + 0.405511314584 + 0.091160625930
 + 0.243752782720 + 0.563265391730 + 0.938591630157 + 0.053376502849 + 0.176084585660 + 0.212015784524
 + 0.093291552095 + 0.272949310717 + 0.697415829563 + 0.296772790257 + 0.302205095562 + 0.928446954142
 + 0.033615064623 + 0.038778684994 + 0.743281078457 + 0.931343341817 + 0.995992351352 + 0.803282407390
 + 0.714717982763 + 0.002658373156 + 0.366005349525 + 0.569351286490 + 0.515456813437 + 0.193641742784
 + 0.188781686796 + 0.622488518613 + 0.632796984155 + 0.343964602031 + 0.494069912343 + 0.891150139880
 + 0.526788287274 + 0.066698500327 + 0.236622057166 + 0.249176977739 + 0.881250574063 + 0.940333075706
 + 0.936703186575 + 0.400023784940 + 0.875090761246 + 0.485734931256 + 0.281568612107 + 0.493793875212
 + 0.021540268393 + 0.576960812516 + 0.330968114316 + 0.814755318215 + 0.964632238890 + 0.252849647521
 + 0.328316150100 + 0.831418052792 + 0.474425361099 + 0.877461270445 + 0.720632491736 + 0.719074649194
 + 0.698827578293 + 0.378885181918 + 0.661859236288 + 0.169773462717

119 solutions found in 4.039 seconds, sampling 8.21707e-118% of available space.
```

Note that only 46 of the numbers in the sum were computed the other 34 the algorithm chose randomly beforehand.

Comment: Interesting solution. Could this be modified to find a subset of different size in a list of different size as well? (eg 11 out of 624)

Comment: @JohnPuccino Sure, larger N is no problem at all because we only use a subset of c, so everything in excess of our random sample will just be ignored. Larger k also is no problem; if it becomes too large we can take a random subset s' of size l of c, add it to s and then solve for k-l in place of k and s+sum(s') in place of s. I'll update the post.

Comment: @JohnPuccino It's actually small values of k and N that make the problem difficult. If I go down to k=5, N=600 it finds solutions but will often need a few trials. At k=4 it found nothing in 1000 trials. But in this regime a brute-force enumeration strategy can be used to check whether there actually are any solutions.

Comment: Wow.. a truly amazing solution. Exactly what i was looking for.. thank you!

Comment: @JohnPuccino Actually, I'm curious where this question comes from. Is it some kind of competition or challenge? It looks like a beautiful problem to ask students to solve since there are solutions that do not require any expert knowledge.

Comment: For me it was needed to solve the challenge 'Almost Integer Rock Garden' in the latest 'Week of code' contest at hackerrank

Answer (score 4):

This problem can be formulated as a mathematical program, which enables us to solve it with specialized algorithms like the simplex algorithm in combination with branch and bound. In most cases with branch and bound we only have to look at a fraction of the search tree to find an optimal solution.

In Python there are many libraries for formulating and solving mixed-integer programs. I think [CyLP](https://github.com/coin-or/CyLP) and [PuLP](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/) are among the well known free ones.

```
easy_install pulp
```

PuLP comes with a free solver for integer problems setup if you easy install it, so I recommend using PuLP, if it suffices for your problem.

Here is an implementation of your problem for PuLP:

```
from pulp import *

items = [1.000123,2.192,3.2143124,1.00041,2.0043,3.5]
x = 0.5
tol = 0.001
numstouse = 3

delta = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('listitems', range(len(items)), lowBound = 0, upBound = 1, cat = pulp.LpInteger)
s = pulp.LpVariable('value', lowBound = 0, cat = pulp.LpInteger)
r = pulp.LpVariable('deviation', lowBound = -tol, upBound=tol)

# Model formulation
prob = LpProblem("Sum Problem", LpMinimize)

# Constraints
prob += lpSum([delta[i] * items[i] for i in range(len(items))]) + x + r == s
prob += lpSum([delta[i] for i in range(len(items))]) == numstouse
prob.solve()
print("Found combination: s={} for {}".format(s.value(), tuple(items[i] for i in range(len(items)) if delta[i].value() == 1)))
if LpStatus[prob.status] == "Optimal":
    for i in delta.keys():
        if delta[i].value() == 1:
            print("List item {} is used in the sum with value {}.".format(i, items[i]))
else:
    print("The problem seems to be infeasible.")
```

It is important to note that, while PuLP will solve your problem eventually with the default free solver, commercial solvers [are many many times faster than free ones](http://plato.asu.edu/bench.html). With growing problem size, free solvers may be way slower than commercial ones.

Comment: I don't know that the linear relaxation buys you anything. Probably a straight dynamic program would be better.

Comment: Can you explain what `numstouse` is for?

Comment: OK, I got it, it's the number of delta[i] that are allowed to be 1 (i.e : the number of elements you pick in the list)

Comment: I can confirm that this solution can handle 600 entries with lists of size 10 in a few seconds

Comment: After I had a little misconception initially about the problem I do not know how this would compare to the enumeration approach though. As pointed out by David, the relaxation may not have much impact.

Comment: Amazing answer and solved the example i was trying it on in just a few seconds. However, the result is not exactly what i was expecting. I configured it like this: x = 12.529964086141668, tol = pow(10,-12), numstouse = 10 and large list of items. If i calculate the sum of x + the list items at the end of the program i get a delta of just 1e-05 instead of the expected 1e-12

Comment: @JohnPuccino In how far is the result different from what you are expecting? The tolerance is very small, there may be issues due to numerical instability.

Comment: I get a correct solution (i.e `error < 10^-12`) with 600 randomly generated numbers. By the way Tristan there is a typo in your code, it's `s.value()-r.value()`. Also, isn't your objective function weird?

Comment: @Tristan I was expecting the delta in the end to be <= 1e-12 if i run it with that "tol". Could the result be made more precise in exchange for a longer program execution time?

Comment: @Fezvez The objective function is not necessary you are right.

Comment: @JohnPuccino PuLP uses CoinOR Solver by default which does likely not have a tolerance of 1e-12. The tolerance can be changed, I am not sure what parameter has to be set though. Maybe you could just multiply everything by a sufficiently large scalar as a test?

Comment: @Tristan: The issue seems to be that the default solver only has a tolerance between 1e-6 and 1e-8. I tried using the glpk solver with param "mipgap 1e-12" instead, but it needed approx 2 hours for one solution while being busy with "integer optimization" most of the time and in the end the resulting delta was 1e-6 as well. Could the code be adjusted or is there any other solver / config option that would allow me to get results with the desired precision of 1e-12?

Comment: It's really weird, for me everything works fine. Could you share your 600 entries. For example by sharing a google doc or dropbox?

Comment: @Fezvez Sure you can find the complete code with sample data i was trying here: https://trinket.io/python/17abe3aaa4 - if i run that code the bottom part which is verifying the sum of x and the calculated subset returns something like "VerifySum: 5.000035560426193, delta=3.556042619301536e-05 => NOT OK" because the delta is just 1e-05 instead of less or equal to the defined tolerance of 1e-12

Comment: @JohnPuccino I am afraid this approach will not work for the 1e-12 tolerance, at least not with PuLP. In theory a lower tolerance could be set, but I do not know about the implications for computational efficiency.

Comment: @JohnPuccino As a test I tried a different solver, which had a minimum possible tolerance of 1e-9 though. It quickly found the following solution to your test data: [119, 174, 190, 24, 253, 277, 292, 388, 551, 576, 591]

Comment: @Tristan Thats a better result, but unfortunately still not as accurate as i need it

Answer (score 0):

It's not as good as I expected, but I have spent far too much time on this to not share it

My idea was that you could reduce the problem from O(n^10) to O(n^5) by splitting the subset of size 10 in 2.

First, compute all subsets of size 5, then sort them by their sum modulo 1 (so that the sum is between 0 and 1)

Then an answer consists of adding two subsets of size 5 such that :

- these subsets do not intersect
- the total sum is either `<e`, `>1-e and <1+e` or `>2-e` with `e` being `10^-12` in your case

Each one of these 3 checks is really cheap if you iterate over the subsets of size 5 smartly (really, that's the part that brings O(n^10) to O(n^5))

So yes, this solution is O(n^5). The problem is that my solution :

- is in Python, which is not the fastest language around
- still requires to compute all combinations of size 5, and "Choose 5 among 600" is untractable (637262850120 combinations)

Edit : I just grab random subsets of size 40 of the large list of size 600 and test all the combinations. If it doesn't work, I grab a new random subset and do it again. It could be improved by being multithreaded

The output was found for `step==44` after 20 minutes and is :

```
l = [0.06225774829854913, 0.21267040355189515, 0.21954445729288707, 0.21954445729288707, 0.24621125123532117, 0.24621125123532117, 0.36931687685298087, 0.4017542509913792, 0.41421356237309515, 0.41640786499873883, 0.6619037896906015]
>>> sum(l) + 0.529964086141668
3.999999999955324
```

---

Watch out for the hack that skips the first 43 steps, comment it if you want to do a real computation

```
from math import pow
from itertools import combinations
import itertools
import random
import time

# Constants
random.seed(1)
listLength = 40
halfsize = 5
halfsize2 = 6
x = 0.529964086141668
epsilon = pow(10,-10)

# Define your list here
#myList = [random.random() for i in range(listLength)]
items = [0.9705627484771391, 0.2788205960997061, 0.620499351813308, 0.0, 0.4222051018559565, 0.892443989449804, 0.41640786499873883, 0.0, 0.6491106406735181, 0.36931687685298087, 0.16552506059643868, 0.04159457879229578, 0.0, 0.04159457879229578, 0.16552506059643868, 0.36931687685298087, 0.6491106406735181, 0.0, 0.41640786499873883, 0.892443989449804, 0.4222051018559565, 0.0, 0.620499351813308, 0.2788205960997061, 0.9705627484771391, 0.2788205960997061, 0.556349186104045, 0.866068747318506, 0.21267040355189515, 0.6014705087354439, 0.038404810405298306, 0.5299640861416677, 0.08304597359457233, 0.7046999107196257, 0.4017542509913792, 0.18033988749894903, 0.045361017187261155, 0.0, 0.045361017187261155, 0.18033988749894903, 0.4017542509913792, 0.7046999107196257, 0.08304597359457233, 0.5299640861416677, 0.038404810405298306, 0.6014705087354439, 0.21267040355189515, 0.866068747318506, 0.556349186104045, 0.2788205960997061, 0.620499351813308, 0.866068747318506, 0.142135623730951, 0.45362404707370985, 0.8062484748656971, 0.20655561573370207, 0.6619037896906015, 0.18033988749894903, 0.7703296142690075, 0.4403065089105507, 0.19803902718556898, 0.049875621120889946, 0.0, 0.049875621120889946, 0.19803902718556898, 0.4403065089105507, 0.7703296142690075, 0.18033988749894903, 0.6619037896906015, 0.20655561573370207, 0.8062484748656971, 0.45362404707370985, 0.142135623730951, 0.866068747318506, 0.620499351813308, 0.0, 0.21267040355189515, 0.45362404707370985, 0.7279220613578552, 0.04159457879229578, 0.4017542509913792, 0.8166538263919687, 0.2956301409870008, 0.8488578017961039, 0.4868329805051381, 0.21954445729288707, 0.0553851381374173, 0.0, 0.0553851381374173, 0.21954445729288707, 0.4868329805051381, 0.8488578017961039, 0.2956301409870008, 0.8166538263919687, 0.4017542509913792, 0.04159457879229578, 0.7279220613578552, 0.45362404707370985, 0.21267040355189515, 0.0, 0.4222051018559565, 0.6014705087354439, 0.8062484748656971, 0.04159457879229578, 0.31370849898476116, 0.63014581273465, 0.0, 0.43398113205660316, 0.9442719099991592, 0.5440037453175304, 0.24621125123532117, 0.06225774829854913, 0.0, 0.06225774829854913, 0.24621125123532117, 0.5440037453175304, 0.9442719099991592, 0.43398113205660316, 0.0, 0.63014581273465, 0.31370849898476116, 0.04159457879229578, 0.8062484748656971, 0.6014705087354439, 0.4222051018559565, 0.892443989449804, 0.038404810405298306, 0.20655561573370207, 0.4017542509913792, 0.63014581273465, 0.8994949366116654, 0.21954445729288707, 0.6023252670426267, 0.06225774829854913, 0.6157731058639087, 0.28010988928051805, 0.0710678118654755, 0.0, 0.0710678118654755, 0.28010988928051805, 0.6157731058639087, 0.06225774829854913, 0.6023252670426267, 0.21954445729288707, 0.8994949366116654, 0.63014581273465, 0.4017542509913792, 0.20655561573370207, 0.038404810405298306, 0.892443989449804, 0.41640786499873883, 0.5299640861416677, 0.6619037896906015, 0.8166538263919687, 0.0, 0.21954445729288707, 0.48528137423856954, 0.810249675906654, 0.21110255092797825, 0.7082039324993694, 0.32455532033675905, 0.08276253029821934, 0.0, 0.08276253029821934, 0.32455532033675905, 0.7082039324993694, 0.21110255092797825, 0.810249675906654, 0.48528137423856954, 0.21954445729288707, 0.0, 0.8166538263919687, 0.6619037896906015, 0.5299640861416677, 0.41640786499873883, 0.0, 0.08304597359457233, 0.18033988749894903, 0.2956301409870008, 0.43398113205660316, 0.6023252670426267, 0.810249675906654, 0.0710678118654755, 0.40312423743284853, 0.8309518948453007, 0.38516480713450374, 0.09901951359278449, 0.0, 0.09901951359278449, 0.38516480713450374, 0.8309518948453007, 0.40312423743284853, 0.0710678118654755, 0.810249675906654, 0.6023252670426267, 0.43398113205660316, 0.2956301409870008, 0.18033988749894903, 0.08304597359457233, 0.0, 0.6491106406735181, 0.7046999107196257, 0.7703296142690075, 0.8488578017961039, 0.9442719099991592, 0.06225774829854913, 0.21110255092797825, 0.40312423743284853, 0.6568542494923806, 0.0, 0.4721359549995796, 0.12310562561766059, 0.0, 0.12310562561766059, 0.4721359549995796, 0.0, 0.6568542494923806, 0.40312423743284853, 0.21110255092797825, 0.06225774829854913, 0.9442719099991592, 0.8488578017961039, 0.7703296142690075, 0.7046999107196257, 0.6491106406735181, 0.36931687685298087, 0.4017542509913792, 0.4403065089105507, 0.4868329805051381, 0.5440037453175304, 0.6157731058639087, 0.7082039324993694, 0.8309518948453007, 0.0, 0.24264068711928477, 0.6055512754639891, 0.16227766016837952, 0.0, 0.16227766016837952, 0.6055512754639891, 0.24264068711928477, 0.0, 0.8309518948453007, 0.7082039324993694, 0.6157731058639087, 0.5440037453175304, 0.4868329805051381, 0.4403065089105507, 0.4017542509913792, 0.36931687685298087, 0.16552506059643868, 0.18033988749894903, 0.19803902718556898, 0.21954445729288707, 0.24621125123532117, 0.28010988928051805, 0.32455532033675905, 0.38516480713450374, 0.4721359549995796, 0.6055512754639891, 0.8284271247461903, 0.2360679774997898, 0.0, 0.2360679774997898, 0.8284271247461903, 0.6055512754639891, 0.4721359549995796, 0.38516480713450374, 0.32455532033675905, 0.28010988928051805, 0.24621125123532117, 0.21954445729288707, 0.19803902718556898, 0.18033988749894903, 0.16552506059643868, 0.04159457879229578, 0.045361017187261155, 0.049875621120889946, 0.0553851381374173, 0.06225774829854913, 0.0710678118654755, 0.08276253029821934, 0.09901951359278449, 0.12310562561766059, 0.16227766016837952, 0.2360679774997898, 0.41421356237309515, 0.0, 0.41421356237309515, 0.2360679774997898, 0.16227766016837952, 0.12310562561766059, 0.09901951359278449, 0.08276253029821934, 0.0710678118654755, 0.06225774829854913, 0.0553851381374173, 0.049875621120889946, 0.045361017187261155, 0.04159457879229578, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.04159457879229578, 0.045361017187261155, 0.049875621120889946, 0.0553851381374173, 0.06225774829854913, 0.0710678118654755, 0.08276253029821934, 0.09901951359278449, 0.12310562561766059, 0.16227766016837952, 0.2360679774997898, 0.41421356237309515, 0.0, 0.41421356237309515, 0.2360679774997898, 0.16227766016837952, 0.12310562561766059, 0.09901951359278449, 0.08276253029821934, 0.0710678118654755, 0.06225774829854913, 0.0553851381374173, 0.049875621120889946, 0.045361017187261155, 0.04159457879229578, 0.16552506059643868, 0.18033988749894903, 0.19803902718556898, 0.21954445729288707, 0.24621125123532117, 0.28010988928051805, 0.32455532033675905, 0.38516480713450374, 0.4721359549995796, 0.6055512754639891, 0.8284271247461903, 0.2360679774997898, 0.0, 0.2360679774997898, 0.8284271247461903, 0.6055512754639891, 0.4721359549995796, 0.38516480713450374, 0.32455532033675905, 0.28010988928051805, 0.24621125123532117, 0.21954445729288707, 0.19803902718556898, 0.18033988749894903, 0.16552506059643868, 0.36931687685298087, 0.4017542509913792, 0.4403065089105507, 0.4868329805051381, 0.5440037453175304, 0.6157731058639087, 0.7082039324993694, 0.8309518948453007, 0.0, 0.24264068711928477, 0.6055512754639891, 0.16227766016837952, 0.0, 0.16227766016837952, 0.6055512754639891, 0.24264068711928477, 0.0, 0.8309518948453007, 0.7082039324993694, 0.6157731058639087, 0.5440037453175304, 0.4868329805051381, 0.4403065089105507, 0.4017542509913792, 0.36931687685298087, 0.6491106406735181, 0.7046999107196257, 0.7703296142690075, 0.8488578017961039, 0.9442719099991592, 0.06225774829854913, 0.21110255092797825, 0.40312423743284853, 0.6568542494923806, 0.0, 0.4721359549995796, 0.12310562561766059, 0.0, 0.12310562561766059, 0.4721359549995796, 0.0, 0.6568542494923806, 0.40312423743284853, 0.21110255092797825, 0.06225774829854913, 0.9442719099991592, 0.8488578017961039, 0.7703296142690075, 0.7046999107196257, 0.6491106406735181, 0.0, 0.08304597359457233, 0.18033988749894903, 0.2956301409870008, 0.43398113205660316, 0.6023252670426267, 0.810249675906654, 0.0710678118654755, 0.40312423743284853, 0.8309518948453007, 0.38516480713450374, 0.09901951359278449, 0.0, 0.09901951359278449, 0.38516480713450374, 0.8309518948453007, 0.40312423743284853, 0.0710678118654755, 0.810249675906654, 0.6023252670426267, 0.43398113205660316, 0.2956301409870008, 0.18033988749894903, 0.08304597359457233, 0.0, 0.41640786499873883, 0.5299640861416677, 0.6619037896906015, 0.8166538263919687, 0.0, 0.21954445729288707, 0.48528137423856954, 0.810249675906654, 0.21110255092797825, 0.7082039324993694, 0.32455532033675905, 0.08276253029821934, 0.0, 0.08276253029821934, 0.32455532033675905, 0.7082039324993694, 0.21110255092797825, 0.810249675906654, 0.48528137423856954, 0.21954445729288707, 0.0, 0.8166538263919687, 0.6619037896906015, 0.41640786499873883, 0.892443989449804, 0.038404810405298306, 0.20655561573370207, 0.4017542509913792, 0.63014581273465, 0.8994949366116654, 0.21954445729288707, 0.6023252670426267, 0.06225774829854913, 0.6157731058639087, 0.28010988928051805, 0.0710678118654755, 0.0, 0.0710678118654755, 0.28010988928051805, 0.6157731058639087, 0.06225774829854913, 0.6023252670426267, 0.21954445729288707, 0.8994949366116654, 0.63014581273465, 0.4017542509913792, 0.20655561573370207, 0.038404810405298306, 0.892443989449804, 0.4222051018559565, 0.6014705087354439, 0.8062484748656971, 0.04159457879229578, 0.31370849898476116, 0.63014581273465, 0.0, 0.43398113205660316, 0.9442719099991592, 0.5440037453175304, 0.24621125123532117, 0.06225774829854913, 0.0, 0.06225774829854913, 0.24621125123532117, 0.5440037453175304, 0.9442719099991592, 0.43398113205660316, 0.0, 0.63014581273465, 0.31370849898476116, 0.04159457879229578, 0.8062484748656971, 0.6014705087354439, 0.4222051018559565, 0.0, 0.21267040355189515, 0.45362404707370985, 0.7279220613578552, 0.04159457879229578, 0.4017542509913792, 0.8166538263919687, 0.2956301409870008, 0.8488578017961039, 0.4868329805051381, 0.21954445729288707, 0.0553851381374173, 0.0, 0.0553851381374173, 0.21954445729288707, 0.4868329805051381, 0.8488578017961039, 0.2956301409870008, 0.8166538263919687, 0.4017542509913792, 0.04159457879229578, 0.7279220613578552, 0.45362404707370985, 0.21267040355189515, 0.0, 0.620499351813308, 0.866068747318506, 0.142135623730951, 0.45362404707370985, 0.8062484748656971, 0.20655561573370207, 0.6619037896906015, 0.18033988749894903, 0.7703296142690075, 0.4403065089105507, 0.19803902718556898, 0.049875621120889946, 0.0, 0.049875621120889946, 0.19803902718556898, 0.4403065089105507, 0.7703296142690075, 0.18033988749894903, 0.6619037896906015, 0.20655561573370207, 0.8062484748656971, 0.45362404707370985, 0.142135623730951, 0.866068747318506, 0.620499351813308, 0.2788205960997061, 0.556349186104045, 0.866068747318506, 0.21267040355189515, 0.6014705087354439, 0.038404810405298306, 0.5299640861416677, 0.08304597359457233, 0.7046999107196257, 0.4017542509913792, 0.18033988749894903, 0.045361017187261155, 0.0, 0.045361017187261155, 0.18033988749894903, 0.4017542509913792, 0.7046999107196257, 0.08304597359457233, 0.5299640861416677, 0.038404810405298306, 0.6014705087354439, 0.21267040355189515, 0.866068747318506, 0.556349186104045, 0.2788205960997061, 0.9705627484771391, 0.2788205960997061, 0.620499351813308, 0.0, 0.4222051018559565, 0.892443989449804, 0.41640786499873883, 0.0, 0.6491106406735181, 0.36931687685298087, 0.16552506059643868, 0.04159457879229578, 0.0, 0.04159457879229578, 0.16552506059643868, 0.36931687685298087, 0.6491106406735181, 0.0, 0.41640786499873883, 0.892443989449804, 0.4222051018559565, 0.0, 0.620499351813308, 0.2788205960997061, 0.9705627484771391]
items = sorted(items)
#print(len(items))
#print(items)

itemSet = sorted(list(set(items)))
#print(len(itemSet))
#print(itemSet)
#print(myList)

#Utility functions
#s is a set of indices
def mySum(s):
  return (sum([myList[i] for i in s]))%1

def mySum2(s):
  return (sum([myList[i] for i in s]) + x)%1


start = time.time()


for step in range(1, 1000000):

    myList = random.sample(items,  listLength)
    # HACK
    if(step<44):
        continue

    print("Step %s"%(step))
    myList = sorted(myList)

    listHalfIndices = [i for i in combinations(range(len(myList)),halfsize)]
    listHalfIndices1 = sorted(listHalfIndices, key = mySum)
    #print(listHalfIndices)
    #print([mySum(s) for s in listHalfIndices])

    listHalfIndices2 = [i for i in combinations(range(len(myList)),halfsize2)]
    listHalfIndices2 = sorted(listHalfIndices2, key = mySum2)
    #print(listHalfIndices2)
    #print([mySum2(s) for s in listHalfIndices2])
    """
    # SKIP THIS as I heuristically noted that it was pretty useless
    # First answer if the sum of the first and second list is smaller than epsilon
    print("ANSWER TYPE 1")
    #print([mySum(s) for s in listHalfIndices1[0:10]])
    #print([mySum2(s) for s in listHalfIndices2[0:10]])


    listLowIndices1 = [s for s in listHalfIndices1 if mySum(s) <= epsilon]
    #print(listLowIndices1)
    #print([mySum(s) for s in listLowIndices1])

    listLowIndices2 = [s for s in listHalfIndices2 if mySum2(s) <= epsilon]
    #print(listLowIndices2)
    #print([mySum2(s) for s in listLowIndices2])

    combinationOfIndices1 = [list(set(sum(i, ()))) for i in itertools.chain(itertools.product(listLowIndices1, listLowIndices2))]
    #print(combinationOfIndices1)
    #print([mySum2(s) for s in combinationOfIndices1])

    answer1 = [i for i in combinationOfIndices1 if len(i) == (2*halfsize) and mySum2(i)<=epsilon]
    if(len(answer1) > 0):
        print (answer1)
        print([mySum2(s) for s in answer1])
        break

    # Second answer if the sum of the first and second list is larger than 2-epsilon
    print("ANSWER TYPE 2")
    #print([mySum(s) for s in listHalfIndices1[-10:-1]])
    #print([mySum2(s) for s in listHalfIndices2[-10:-1]])

    listHighIndices1 = [s for s in listHalfIndices1 if mySum(s) >= 1-epsilon]
    #print(listHighIndices1)

    listHighIndices2 = [s for s in listHalfIndices2 if mySum2(s) >= 1-epsilon]
    #print(listHighIndices2)

    combinationOfIndices2 = [list(set(sum(i, ()))) for i in itertools.chain(itertools.product(listHighIndices1, listHighIndices2))]
    #print(combinationOfIndices2)
    #print([mySum2(s) for s in combinationOfIndices2])

    answer2 = [i for i in combinationOfIndices2 if len(i) == (2*halfsize) and mySum2(i)>=1-epsilon]
    if(len(answer2) > 0):
        print (answer2)
        print([mySum2(s) for s in answer2])
        break
    """
    # Third answer if the sum of the first and second list is between 1-epsilon and 1+epsilon
    #print("ANSWER TYPE 3")
    i = 0
    j = len(listHalfIndices2) - 1
    answer3 = None
    print("Answer of type 3 will explore at most %s combinations "%(2*len(listHalfIndices2)))
    for k in range(2*len(listHalfIndices2)): 
        if(k%1000000 == 0 and k>0):
                print(k)
        setOfIndices = list(set(listHalfIndices1[i] + listHalfIndices2[j]))
        #print(setOfIndices)

        currentSum = mySum(listHalfIndices1[i]) + mySum2(listHalfIndices2[j])
        #print(currentSum)
        if(currentSum < 1-epsilon):
            i = i+1
            if(i>=len(listHalfIndices1)):
                break
            #print("i++")
        else:
            j = j-1
            if(j<0):
              break
            #print("j--")
        if(len(setOfIndices) < (halfsize+halfsize2)):
            #print("skipping")
            continue

        if(currentSum >= 1-epsilon and currentSum <= 1+epsilon):
            print("Found smart combination with sum : s=%s"%(currentSum))
            print(sorted([myList[i] for i in setOfIndices]))
            answer3 = setOfIndices
            break

    if answer3 is not None:
        break

end = time.time()
print("Time elapsed %s"%(end-start))
```